# How to check POST request headers before receiving and parsing request body?

Tags: node.js, rest, http, express, koa

When a POST request is received, is there any way to check its headers, before receiving the request body and parsing it?

Imagine you have very large incoming POST requests (~25MB) and you need to decide whether to process them or discard them based on their headers' content.

To spare bandwith, memory, cpu, and time it would be much better if it could be possible to have this flow:

1. The POST request hits the server.
2. The server only receives it up to the headers content, and then holds the transmission on standby.
3. The server checks the headers and decides what to do.
4. If the headers are ok it proceeds receiving the request and parses the body, otherwise it closes the connection and sends a 401 reply.

Is this possible at all? If so, what is a good way to do it in [Koa](http://koajs.com/)?

Thanks!

Comment: How about checking the `request.headers` with some middleware?

Comment: @tymeJV is there any way to make sure that receiving the request body is suspended until the request headers are verified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't check the headers before "receiving" the body. If you wanted to do something like that, you'd need create a custom function that reads bytes from a socket, and parses only the headers, and closes the connection in case of certain logic, which is probably more work than you're willing to do.

What you CAN do, is create a middleware function that reads the headers and then either a) continues on to the next middleware or b) ends the request. You can then make it so that this middleware is executed BEFORE the body parsing middleware (if you're using something like koa-body). This way, although the body is already "received", the request is sent before the body is even parsed.

It's pretty easy to implement something like this, and there are plenty of guides outlining the process for creating and registering new middleware. If you do not already know how to do it, I suggest starting [here](https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/docs/guide.md).

EDIT: If you're doing file uploads and you're using multipart then it should be not a problem to check the headers using a middleware function and send a 401. That will terminate the connection and the file upload, as long as you do it before you start parsing the upload.

Comment: Hi @Yuri, thanks for your answer! I added some question details above. The point is that it's unefficient to receive the entire body each time, before reading the headers. In fact, if the headers are not ok, the request is discarded. So, it would be much better to receive the body only after checking the headers, if they're ok. Not sure if this is possible though, and how complicated it would be.

Comment: I see... one last thing: what if it's not multipart, but just a very large 'application/json'? Would your suggested approach still be valid? Thanks!

Comment: @Pensierinmusica If it isn't multipart then you might be better off sending an initial request with no data and if the headers are fine respond with OK but if the headers aren't fine respond with Bad Request. Then the client can decide whether to resend the request with the entire body of data when it receives the initial response from the server. The disadvantage is that this requires two round trips. I don't really see any other approach.